# Collecting a Boundary of an Area using ODK

Tags: open-data-kit

I am trying to get a geo shape of a place here and I'm using ODK Collect to Map the area. I am able to create the Geo shape using ODK but the problem is, I am not able to export this data to QGIS for use and create shapefiles.

I do not know how I can do this or if there is another tool I can use.

Comment: I know this question is explicitly about ODK, but as you seem to use ODK just for collecting a shape: why not use something like QField instead? You can simply drop your QGIS projct in there/export it right away into QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the data into the most recent version of ODK Briefcase (either by connecting the collection device by USB cable, or by pulling data from Aggregate), then Briefcase can export a GeoJSON file that QGIS will read easily.